# WHM/cPanel SSL Warning in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, cpanel, whm

I'm managing a server running CentOS, and when I try to log in to WHM at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2087 I've always got a warning saying "This is probably not the site you are looking for!" [image: (http://grab.by/x20A)].
I did a little Googling and came up with installing a self-signed SSL certificate (http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/#.U3sX31hdWDS) so I did that. I created the certificate for the IP of the server, and installed it to my keychain then restarted Chrome.

Now when I visit the IP to log, I still get the same warning message, except that it says I attempted to reach the IP [abc.def.ghi.jkl] and the server identifies itself as the **same** IP [abc.def.ghi.jkl]. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up HOSTNAME (public domain like host.mydomain.com) for server remote access. Other hostnames for mail servers like smtp, pop, imap, ftp should be configured like the same. Make sure to updated DNS for all registered host and instance names.

WHM/Cpanel creates default self-signed ssl, this ssl never works. You should purchase Trusted CA certificate for hostname you’ll use to access server on remote like host.mydomain.com.
As per CAB forum guideline, no CA will provide you ssl for IP address.

**Conclusion:**

Set up server remote access hostname > purchase SSL for public domain hostnames.

It should work fine like :

https://host.abcdomain.com/whm

https://host.abcdomain.com:2087

https://host.abcdomain.com/cpanel

If you need to configure a single host name on ssl, you should purchase single domain ssl.

If you need ssl for host, pop, ftp, smtp and more, you should purchase wildcard ssl certificate.